# How to type ramda's ifElse function in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, ramda.js

I was trying to improve the typing of ifElse in ramda which currently has a sad type of
`export function ifElse(fn: Pred, onTrue: Arity2Fn, onFalse: Arity2Fn): Arity2Fn;`

However I very quickly hit the limits of typescript (read: my skills) when I try to improve it:

```js
type Pred = <T>(o: T) => boolean
type Branch = <T>(o: T) => any
type Prop = <T, K extends keyof T>(k: K) => (o: T) => T[K]

type IfElseBase = (p: Pred, t: Branch, f: Branch) => (obj: any) => any

type IfElse = IfElseBase extends (
    (p: (obj: any) => infer RP, t: (obj: any) => infer RT, f: (obj: any) => infer RF) => (obj: infer OBJ) => any)
     ? (p: (o: OBJ) => RP, t: (o: OBJ) => RT, f: (o: OBJ) => RF) => (o: OBJ) => RP extends true ? RT : RF
     : IfElseBase
    

// who cares about the real code, anyway?
const ifElse: IfElse = null as any
const prop: Prop = null as any
const propEq: <T, K extends keyof T>(key: K, val: T[K]) => (obj: T) => boolean = (k, v) => (o) => o[k] === v

type Test = {
    flag: boolean
    right: "ok",
    wrong: "urgs" 
}

const input: Test = {
    flag: true,
    right: "ok",
    wrong: "urgs" 
}

const output = ifElse(propEq("flag", true), prop("right"), prop("wrong"))(input) // any but should be "ok"
```

As [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBACgThAJlAvFAPAFQHwAoD2AXFJgJSrZQBG++ANhAIYB2AsAFCiRQBCcLAYwAWqDDgLEyFKCxAcu0ePjCisAGigBpKBAAewCM0QBnKAGsIIfADMSeM8U3kUlCSWeVMAbU0BdDvLg0ACS1gCidMYQPIxRorhgxPBIGsDEfIJCGtbp-MzCHlAEVABWxLKFsgGcQVChEXFo9ZHRsdB6BkamuBxQfUWJRfil5cwghQCWzNYQcFAASjCpxMVlMmOT07MLmNkrw2sV0lMzc-MAYoWrxCfbAPI8AFKVG739UAD8A-vED8-Si2WQ1+T0K812UBywKgfzBl2kblhAJgOn0hhMUGAcAArtAvuCoMQLm9+sRmlEYlESVBqgB6WlQADuQnwUAEjAQpkYNGxwExQmgCEYdDZ+EQEA0skZjBAHw4AnwzGMfIm4RaZLVjSgzGxdBFsXWcnYCqVfLAcGUSQtKjQOr1Mi5Y3liuVUHNyjCAEdiOotKjOhiLFZbOIg44NAA3YWSHy+K4HSSFGj0JjMeJmSPxwr4LxmXyoFBoCPVBQkCCutAAb2p1jojAA5sRkwwWNS4BN60I0lAAET4Mw9tTUxkW5iN3vYuD14w9mnsAC+1RNrqmYF5knLfKrNbr46xuKH7He7c73b7A8P7xHivHPcn09nHEX7Gdpqg+F5a63UFVDQgCWtL1cB7WsG0HTEcQgUgNHdMBgJPLse2gt1rWA68xyQ0hcFXXlyHpQ1qF5KBjBZXVkCoaBzx7aogA)

Answer (score 0):

The best variant I was able to implement, was not to use conditional ramda functions. For example, instead of `when(is(String), pipe(split('/'), last))` in pipe, I was forced to use

```
pipe(
  (maybeLink) => is(String, maybeLink) ? last(split('/', maybeLink)) : maybeLink,
  ...
)
```

Comment: I think with the 0.28 branch things have improved and ifElse is now properly typed